# Qt NetworkAccessManager how to download file via HTTP

Tags: qt, http, download, qnetworkaccessmanager

today i began a project using Qt, and i am having a little trouble downloading files with NetworkAccessManager. I am very new to Qt and dont quite understand the structure yet, so please bee beginner friendly with your suggestions =)

if it is at all possible, would you be able to post some code to help me out? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extremely simplified code. All kinds of checks are removed. It is not meant to be copy/pasted into a production system. No logins. No ssl.

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(QUrl(source)); // source = url to the file you want to download.
manager->get(request);
```

The replyFinished slot:

```
replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply){
 reply->deleteLater();
 QByteArray yourFile = reply->readAll();
}
```

Again: Check the docs for details, e.g. error handling. For simplification I assumed, that really the full content of your file is already available when replyFinished is called.